# Finding some value from a long string

Tags: javascript

The above string has following parts

Part 1: 22208 : INCISE SPINE 3 COLUMN ADL SEG [can be of any Length]

Part 2: ü [this is used as separator]

Part 3: certified [can be of value certified/noncertified/pending]

Part 4: ~ [this is again used as separator]

Part 5: 12/12/2012 [Date will be entered as : mm/dd/yyyy]

so I want to do the part 3 and part 4 in separate alerts but I am caught in a mess here, my JS is not strong enough, here is my bit of try:

```
var index = myObject[row].indexOf("ü");
var index2 = myObject[row].indexOf("~");
var statusCPT = myObject[row].substr(index+1)
var statusCPT = statusCPT
var statusDate = myObject[row].substr(index2+1)
alert(statusCPT);
alert(statusDate);
```

Tried the way I am doing it (I changed the ~ to Σ)

Here is my build in script:

```
destinationObject[destinationObject.length] = 
    document.frmDiagEdit.DiagnosisCPT.value + 'ü' +
    newstatus + 'Σ' + newdateStatus;
```

where the last two components are optional. On the all the string is build like this:

```
22208 : INCISE SPINE 3 COLUMN ADL SEGücertifiedΣ12/12/2012
```

It should give me 3 different rows in alerts separating all three, and if the date is not defined at all, it show 2 only

that's all is in the script

Comment: you should use regular expressions for this, e.g. `str.match(/(.+?)ü(.+?)~(.+)/)`

Comment: Why do you have the `var statusCPT` twice?

Comment: @Bergi: Typo mistake sorry

Comment: @Gurpreet: Then please fix it by [edit]ing your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well try learning regular expressions.

You can get them using match or split methods with regex . Try this in firebug. Since you have sepeartors you can easily split using split or match and regexps

```
"22208 : INCISE SPINE 3 COLUMN ADL SEGücertifiedΣ12/12/2012".match(/ü(.+)Σ/)
```

Comment: Thanks and let me test it [Well i really need to lean regular expresions]

Comment: I tried like this `<script>
var str ="22208 : INCISE SPINE 3 COLUMN ADL SEGücertifiedΣ12/12/2012";
var i = str.match(/(.+?)ü(.+?)Σ(.+)/);
alert(i);

var cccc ="22208 : INCISE SPINE 3 COLUMN ADL SEGücertified";
var k = cccc.match(/(.+?)ü(.+?)Σ(.+)/);
alert(k);
</script>` First time it showed records, second time it showed null

Comment: the string even contains comma, spaces and colons that should be retained, currently match is not doing that